# Pickling C Objects in Python

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to pickle some keypoint objects from opencv. Pickle doesn't seem to support this, so I'm trying to add a reduce method via copy_reg:

```
key = cv2.KeyPoint

# Add pickle function to keypoints
def pickle_kp(kp):
  return key, (kp.x, kp.y, kp._size, kp._angle,
                        kp._response, kp._octave, kp._class_id,)
copy_reg.pickle(key, pickle_kp, key)

kp = key(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
pickle.dumps(kp)
```

I still get the pickling error:

```
pickle.dumps(kp)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1374, in dumps
    Pickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 306, in save
    rv = reduce(self.proto)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py", line 70, in _reduce_ex
    raise TypeError, "can't pickle %s objects" % base.__name__
TypeError: can't pickle KeyPoint objects
```

Is it not possible to use copy_reg in this way?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible that there are two types, like a `cv2.KeyPoint` that's a Python wrapper around a `_cv2.KeyPoint`, and you've registered a picklers for one but the other one still isn't picklable (and, since they have the same `__name__`, the error message is confusing)?

Comment: Good idea! It does seem that's the case, as help(cv2.KeyPoint) indicates that cv2.KeyPoint is a function and not a class constructor. I can't seem to figure out where the class exists in the namespace though...

Comment: I didn't even consider the fact that `cv2.KeyPoint` might be a constructor function rather than a class, but yeah, that would definitely do it… Anyway, if you have a `KeyPoint` object (either in the interactive session, or in the middle of your program), try printing out `type(keypoint_object),__module__`. That will always work for pure-Python types, and usually work for C types. (If it doesn't work, you may have to grub through the source, but hopefully it won't come to that.)